# File uploading and downloading via remote method invocation

Tags: java, network-programming, rmi

I spend the day working and working on how my client can upload and download files from the server database. My code works fine when the server and client run on the same machine but when the client is on the different machine as well as the server, everything messed up. This is my project for the school so can anyone assist me on how to implement what the program is supposed to do. I search and search all over the internet and for my own effort i failed to find a solution, I saw some but they are servlet and jsp related. I need to do this as a desktop application. For some information regarding my code here it is.

Server Implementation for Downloading :

```
public synchronized void downloadFile(Object row) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+path+".accdb;";
        dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        ps = dbConn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM File WHERE ID = ?");
        ps.setString(1, row.toString());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            InputStream is;
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                is = rs.getBinaryStream("FileSize");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/" +rs.getString("FileName")));
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read()) != -1) {
                    fos.write(c);
                }
                is.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ps.close();
    dBConn.close();

}
```

Here's my actionlistener for download button :

```
if (source.equals(downloadB)) {
            try {
                if (fileTable.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file to be download", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    s.downloadFile(fileTable.getValueAt(fileTable.getSelectedRow(), 0));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Download Successful", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (RemoteException re) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error downloading file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
```

My database containts the following :

ID : Autonumber

FileName : Text

FileSize : OLE Object

Comment: what is value of path?

Comment: well the value of path is simply the path where the database is located.

Comment: Share that file all user and use UNC path to access the file :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't implementing remote file loading over rmi, you have implemented a remote call which copies a database file to the local filesystem (of the server).  unless your client has access to the server's filesystem, this isn't going to work.  you need to actually *send* the file bytes over rmi.

Comment: Both uploading and downloading should be in terms of byte[] coding? Thanks for the enlightenment

Comment: @MaricrisCarbonel - yes, that is the simple solution (which is fine for homework).  for production code, however, you would _never_ want to do that as it will cause memory problems for large files.  you can use [rmiio](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/) to stream data over rmi for a more robust implementation.